# java. Hi, I am learning java and got a bit stuck. I am trying to return an array from a method to the main method

Tags: java

Just wondering if anyone could help me here. I am trying to return an array to the main method and get it to print to screen for me. I am new to coding and am just starting. This code compiles but with no printout. I think I am missing a line of code in the main, but I just cant figure it out. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
public class DivideArray {

    public static void main(String[]args){
        double myNumbers[] ={1.4,3.43,5.6,6.94,8.1,56.2};
        double m = 2.2; 
    }
    public static double[] scaleArray(double m, double myNumbers[]){

        double array1[]= new double[myNumbers.length];
        for(int i =0;i<myNumbers.length;i++){
            array1[i]=myNumbers[i]/m;
        }
        for(int i =0;i<array1.length;i++){
            System.out.println(array1[i]);
        }
                return array1;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to actually call the method in `main`.

Comment: Well, you aren't calling your method. You aren't saving the result. And you aren't printing the result. I do see some attempt at printing in the scale method, and you could certainly do so - but you aren't saving the result, and it's normally better to seperate concerns. So, I'd remove that and just do `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(scaleArray(m, myNumbers)));` in `main`

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow. Please edit your post to improve your title - that's part of why you're getting downvotes.

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to actually call the method in the `main` method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     ...
     ...
     scaleArray(m, myNumbers);
}
...
```

Comment: That is great, thank you so much. I have been confused for a while with this. I had variations of that but never the right one.

Answer (score 0):

Your program is not giving any output because you have defined the method but not actually called it:

```
public class DivideArray {
    public static void main(String[]args){
    double myNumbers[] ={1.4,3.43,5.6,6.94,8.1,56.2};
    double m = 2.2; 
    // below is the line of code that you are missing
    scaleArray(m, myNumbers);
}

public static double[] scaleArray(double m, double myNumbers[]){
    double array1[]= new double[myNumbers.length];
    for(int i =0;i<myNumbers.length;i++){
        array1[i]=myNumbers[i]/m;
    }

    for(int i =0;i<array1.length;i++){
        System.out.println(array1[i]);
    }
    return array1; 
    }
}
```

Comment: That is great, thank you so much. I have been confused for a while with this. I had variations of that but never the right one.